# participle phrase with a comma

Tags: commas, participles

> Mark stood next to Tracy, feeling helplessly nervous.

I have a question about this sentence.

If context is added, according to context, can the sentence mean either 1 or 2 below?

1. Mark stood next to Tracy, and Tracy felt helplessly nervous.
2. Mark stood next to Tracy, and Mark felt helplessly nervous.

I mean without context, the sentence can mean both 1 and 2.

I think so, but I'm not sure whether I'm right.

Comment: It can only be 2)

Comment: @Lambie Then, unlike the sentence in the original post, if context is clear as in this sentence **"Erika rides the bus, billowing black exhaust into the air"**, is it correct to see **"billowing black..the air"** as non-restrictively modifying **"The bus"** because it doesn't make much sense if it's modifying Erika?

Comment: Then the person billowing the black exhaust into the air is Erica, not the bus. :) You have to use and it billows there or as it billows.

Comment: Mark and Erika are the subjects of the respective sentences. The phrase refers to the subject unless otherwise specified - _...the bus, which is billowing..._

Comment: It's theoretically ambiguous. It *could* be interpreted as referring to Tracy—but it would be very unlikely. While similar constructions are more likely to be ambiguous, this particular one is straight forward. (It would take a deliberate act of misinterpretation to think of it differently.) Unfortunately, two sentences with the same construction can have differing degrees of interpretation. It depends on the exact words that are used. For instance: *Mark stood next to the clown, juggling balls.* Despite the similar construction, the ***opposite*** interpretation is more likely.

Comment: In sentences like this, it's always best to rephrase them in order to avoid even any appearance of ambiguity: *Feeling helplessly nervous, Mark stood next to Tracy.* Even if technically they should only be interpreted one way, you sometimes don't know how accurate the author is being with their syntax.

Comment: This is totally incorrect.  An independent clause consisting of a verbal adjective phrase /modifies the subject of the independent clause/. There are not exceptions.  Consider:  "The owner led the dog by the leash, wagging his tail." Any English listener would respond:  "What?  The owner was wagging his tail?" and you'd lose points in an English or writing class for writing that.  If there were any ambiguity whatsoever, it would sound natural and the dog would be wagging.  It doesn't, there is not ambiguity.  The original "feeling nervous" can apply /only to the subject of the sentence/: Mark.

Comment: If you want an adjectival phrase to modify the object instead, you must make a separate SV:  "Mark stood next to Tracy, who was feeling helplessly nervous."  Please do not think it is correct to form sentences such as the "Erika rides the bus..." example, @Zenith.

Answer (score 1):

> Mark stood next to Tracy, feeling helplessly nervous.

^ This means that Mark was standing next to Tracy and he was feeling nervous.  **It cannot mean that Tracy was feeling nervous.**

> Mark stood next to Tracy, who was feeling helpless nervous.

^ This means that Mark was standing next to Tracy, and that Tracy was feeling nervous.  **It cannot mean that Mark was feeling nervous.**

The general rule is that if you have an independent clause (words that can make a complete sentence on their own), followed by a comma, followed by an adjective (or phrase that acts like an adjective), without a noun or  pronoun that acts as a subject, **the adjective modifies the subject of the sentence.**.  This is a basic grammar construct you will see again and again.  The adjective never modifies the object of the sentence or another noun in the sentence in these cases; context does not matter.

> Mark stood next to Tracy, feeling helplessly nervous.

^ Here `Mark` is the subject, `next to Tracy` is an adverbial clause that modifies `stood`, and the phrase `feeling helplessly nervous` functions as an adjective.  There is no noun or pronoun in `feeling helplessly nervous`, so the grammar rule applies. `Feeling` can only modify the subject, `Mark`.

> Mark stood next to Tracy, who was feeling helpless nervous.

^ Here the entire phrase `next to Tracy, who was feeling helpless nervous`, functions as an adverb which modifies `stood`.  Within that phrase, `Tracy, who was feeling helpless nervous` functions as a single noun phrase.

It's also worth noting that the adjectival phrase can occur at many places in the sentence:

> Mark stood next to Tracy, feeling helplessly nervous.
>
> Mark, feeling totally helpless, stood next to Tracy.
>
> Feeling helplessly nervous, Mark stood next to Tracy.

In all of these three, `feeling` modifies `Mark`, the subject of the sentence.  Adjective clause that consist of <verb> + `ing` set off by a comma **always refer to the subject of the clause they modify**.